# for c in string is there a way to find position of c

Tags: python

The Python "for c in string" idiom is good but sometimes you might do a check and find that you need to pass a section of string say to a function.

So for example

```
str = "I am a <token>"
for ch in str:
    if ch == '<':
       # I need to know where in string we are now
```

Is there way way?  Or for this sort of thing should I being doing it a different way?

Comment: `str` is an unfortunate choice of a variable name, as it is also a name of the built-in type.

Comment: Do you want to know the index because you want to extract the substring that is between `<` and `>`? In that case, I'd suggest to use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Silly me - a beginner at Python.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> for i, ch in enumerate(str):
        print i, ch

Would print

0 I
1 
2 a
...
```

You should also be careful while using `str` as a variable name as that's the name of the built-in type.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you need to do something in the loop besides finding the index just use `find`:

```
>>> "I am a <token>".find('<')
7
>>> s = "I am a <token>"
>>> s[s.find('<'):s.find('>')+1]
'<token>'
>>> s[s.find('<')+1:s.find('>')]
'token'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) here. This would iterate over the string while giving you the index values. (There is a second argument which gives a starting number for the index)

```
>>> string = "I am a <token>"
>>> for index, element in enumerate(string):
        if element == '<':
            print index     
7
```

**P.S** - Don't use `str` as a variable name. It shadows the builtin `str` type.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, ch in enumerate(some_string):
    print ch, 'is at index', idx
```